# Default REST API returns deleted items

Tags: odata, sitefinity, sitefinity-10

Our team is leveraging the Sitefinity default REST API (i.e. `/api/default/products`) in order to perform data operations on an external job. We are able to distinguish products by site/provider and culture without issue. This is currently working for the most part but with a frustrating potential bug.

It seems that the API returns the Live version of the content as expected, but it also returns content of that type that has been Deleted and is sitting in the Recycle Bin. Documentation on this has been scarce and I have not seen it mentioned in other posts. I am looking for a parameter or filter that will remove Deleted/Recycle Bin items from the response in the Sitefinity default REST API?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Log a ticket with Progress

Comment: @VeselinVasilev Progress does not allow to create any tickets if you are just the development team and did not purchase any license from them. There are several outsourcing companies who are just implementation experts and do not have licenses.

Comment: @user1400290 this is correct and was the situation I was in. I had to get my account linked to the client's account/license in order to open a support ticket with Progress.

Comment: @JakeHouseholder Yes, that is the only way out. Infact they made their forums read only as well. I think they are cutting cost in technical support. Nevermind, nice meeting you and if you and your team needs sitefinity experts or any other resources for that matter, feel free to messge me and we can take it from there. Our Dev's are based out of india and done some terrific work in sitefinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with Telerik/Progress and they confirmed this is a bug. The rep stated that it will be resolved in Sitefinity 11. For now the only workarounds are to make sure items are unpublished before deleted or removed from the recycle bin. Alternatively, one could create their own endpoints that use the ModuleManagers that provide access to the lifecycle of content.